# como guardar los datos de un entry box en una variable de tipo Datos =[{}]

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola amigos quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con esto,,necesito guardar los datos de unos entry box en una variable de tipo Datos =[{}]
supongamos este codigo

```
from tkinter import *



raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")

nombrelable = Label(miframe,text ="Cuenta de Correo:",font =(16))
nombrelable.grid(row="1",column="0")
passlabel = Label(miframe,text ="Contraseña:",font =(16))
passlabel.grid(row="2",column="0")
agelabel = Label(miframe,text ="age:",font =(16))
agelabel.grid(row="3",column="0")
textocorreo= Entry(miframe,width="30")
textocorreo.grid(row="1",column="1")
textopass= Entry(miframe,width="30")
textopass.grid(row="2",column="1")
textoage= Entry(miframe,width="30")
textoage.grid(row="3",column="1")

def send_data():
    pass

ingresarboton = Button(miframe, text="Ingresar", command=send_data)
ingresarboton.grid(row="11", column="1")
raiz.mainloop()
```

Lo que dese es que cuando se de click en ingresar los datos introducidos en los entry box se guarden en una variable asi

```
cuentas = [
    {
        "Cuenta de Correo": 'alvagarcia197888@gmail.com',
        "Contraseña": 'Maitecera*123456',
        "age": '50'
    },
    {
        "Cuenta de Correo": 'cargarcia12032588@gmail.com',
        "Contraseña": 'Cargarcia*123456',
        "age": '55'
    },
    {
        "Cuenta de Correo": 'mariavalle12057888@gmail.com',
        "Contraseña": 'Mariavalle*123456',
        "age": '45'
    }
]
```

donde cada llave corresponde a una pulsacion del boton  en este caso se han pulsado 3 veces el boton por lo que que habran 3 cuentas de correo con sus respectivos datos,,lo que se quiere es que por cada vez que se pulse el boton se generen de esa forma nuevos datos,,,no se si me hago explicar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es una lista de diccionarios, basta con que en la callback asociada al botón generes cada vez que sea llamada (y después de validar el formulario si es necesario) un nuevo diccionario con las claves que deseas y los valores los tomes desde los Entries mediante el método `get`:

```
cuentas = []
def send_data():
    datos = {
        "Cuenta de Correo": textocorreo.get(),
        "Contraseña": textopass.get(),
        "age": textoage.get()
    }
    cuentas.append(datos)
```

Comment: una vez cerrada la aplicacion los datos guardados en cuentas[] se pierden habria alguna forma de impedir esto ,,es decir abro la aplicacion introduzco algunos datos ,,los guardo ,,cierro la aplicacion y cuando la vuelva a abrir y introduzca nuevos datos estos se sumen a los que ya habia guardado con anterioridad